# Can I use RPCClient with fanout exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and needs some advice.

I have a situation where I need to broadcast a message and then wait for a response in a timely fashion. In other words, the broadcast message expects a response within a timeout period from all subscribing consumers. It's straightforward with direct exchange. I can use a RPCClient to wait for the response. How does it work with fanout exchange? Would it know how many subscriber to wait for? Or would it return successfully after the first response?

If I create a fanout exchange and pass it in when creating the RPCClient object. Then implement my own consumer and and the consumer consumer from the same exchange and sender send to the same reply-to queue. Would it work?

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is your issue:

> the broadcast message expects a response within a timeout period from **all** subscribing consumers.

I added emphasis to illustrate an anti-pattern in your design. The concept behind a broadcast is that the broadcaster neither knows nor cares about who is listening to it. By creating a constraint on the broadcaster to know who is listening, you have effectively changed a broadcast into a bunch of unicasts, but are attempting to do so without actually admitting it.

Now, let me describe a more viable scenario without using the word `all`.

1. You send a broadcast message via a fanout or topic exchange.
2. Consumers receive the message
3. Consumers send a new message to a reply queue via a direct exchange as designated within the original broadcast message.
4. A consumer reading from the reply queue consumes messages until the end of the timeout period.

Hopefully all consumers have replied, but there is no way to know.  If you require a 1 to 1 correspondence between consumer and broadcaster, your situation becomes a lot more complicated and a broadcast is no longer the appropriate venue.

Comment: I agree. I'm trying to update some legacy code written in JMS and it looks like it's using topic queue as if it were a regular queue. Since I don't really have a test case, it made it that much harder to understand. The part that I don't get is that when I create a RPCClient, it listens at one reply-to queue. So now, this RPCClient that broadcast is going to wait for more than one request? Or do I need to hack RPCClient?

Comment: If I don't use the exsiting RPCClient class, I don't know how best to add the timeout. Could you advise? Thanks.

Comment: To address your first comment - I think you really need to ask the questions from your team/predecessor or whoever is asking you to modify the code to understand what you are trying to do. It sounds very odd to me, which means there is probably some fundamental thing they are trying to achieve and telling you "how" instead of "what"

Comment: I read your comment on the answer above. Are you trying to get a heartbeat status from consumers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work. RPC is a pattern (if we exclude direct reply to) not bound to a direct exchange. You can apply this pattern to a fanout exchange.

Instead of waiting for [one reply](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/RPCClient.java#L39-L45), wait for the expected replies or until the timout is reached.

The knowledge of expected replies and fanout exchange are usually antinomic. So you could only rely on the timeout.

Comment: I agree. But how would RPCClient work? By default, RPCClient only wait for one response. So I need to hack the code and put in the loop to do the response retrieval? It's confusing. How is heartbeat command done in a distributed system?